# Drupal google map integration

Tags: drupal-6

I have integrated Google maps in drupal, but when I create a new page Google map shown in the page. How to hide it in the pages except Contact us..?

Answer (score 0):

You have to integrate Google map as a block content.

Try: http://yoursite.test/admin/build/block/add. After adding your Google Map code in the body section of the block, you have to check the "**Show on only the listed pages.**" of "**Page specific visibility settings**" section. Then add the Contact us page relative path in the Pages input box.

FYI: Follow the instruction under the input box

**Now, publish the block in the region where you want to show the Google Map.**. It will show only at the Contact us page.

[image]